# Pinterest V3 API Endpoints

Tags: api, pinterest

I am trying to access the Pinterest API but their documentation is scarce and does not provide the functionality I am looking for.

I'd like to pull JSON of all pins for any given board. I've found this endpoint:

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/boards/highquality/travel/pins/
```

But this seems to only want to return 50 pins from the board. I've tried several schemes for pagination with no success.

Has anyone had experience with this API? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but in case someone else needs some documentation: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/redoc/pinner_app/#operation/v3_board_pins_GET

The endpoint: [https://api.pinterest.com/v3/boards/{board}/pins/](https://api.pinterest.com/v3/boards/%7Bboard%7D/pins/)

The response returns a "bookmark" value to provide pagination.